# Dynamically populate multiple input textboxes using jquery function , based on one input textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textbox, populate

I have an input textbox called idno. Based on an id number added to this textbox, i want to populate 3 other input textboxes using a jquery function that is functional.

My problem is that i need to populate the input text boxes called age,birthdate and gender dynamically from the textbox called idno. Please assist this javascript beginner

This short javascript/jquery code output correct info to the screen when i use it :

```js
<script>
$().ready(function() {
$('#idno').rsa_id_validator({
});
});
</script>


(function($){  
 $.fn.rsa_id_validator = function(options) {  
 
 var defaults = {  
  displayValid: [true,"<font color='#00CC00'>IDNo Valid</font>","<font color='#FF0000'>IDNo InValid</font>"],
  displayDate: [true,"<b>Date of Birth:</b> "],
  displayAge: [true,"<b>Age:</b> "],  
  displayGender: [true,"<b>Gender:</b> Male","<b>Gender:</b> Female"],  
  displayCitizenship: [true,"<b>Citizenship:</b> South African","<b>Citizenship:</b> Foreign Citizenship"],
  displayValid_id: "id_results",
  displayDate_id: "id_results",  
  displayAge_id: "id_results",  
  displayGender_id: "id_results",  
  displayCitizenship_id: "id_results"  
 };  
 var options = $.extend(defaults, options);
  
    return this.each(function() {  
  obj = $(this);
  $(obj).attr('maxlength','13');
  $(obj).keydown(function(event) {
   // Allow: backspace, delete, tab, escape, and enter
   if ( event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 9 || event.keyCode == 27 || event.keyCode == 13 || 
     // Allow: Ctrl+A
    (event.keyCode == 65 && event.ctrlKey === true) || 
     // Allow: home, end, left, right
    (event.keyCode >= 35 && event.keyCode <= 39)) {
      // let it happen, don't do anything
      return;
   }
   else {
    // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
    if (event.shiftKey || (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57) && (event.keyCode < 96 || event.keyCode > 105 )) {
     event.preventDefault(); 
    }   
   }
     });
  
   $(obj).bind("keyup", function(){
   
   //error array creation variables
   var displayResults = [" "," "," "," "," "];
   var html = ""; 
   
   //Variable declaration
   var element_type = "";
   var currentTime = new Date();
   var id_number = $(this).val();
   
   
   //display date of birth
   if(options.displayDate[0] == true){ //start if statement
    if (id_number.length > 5){ //start if statement
     var date = "";
     var year       = id_number.substr ( 0  , 2 );
     var nowYearNotCentury = currentTime.getFullYear() + '';
     nowYearNotCentury = nowYearNotCentury.substr(2,2);
     if (year <= nowYearNotCentury){
      date = '20' + year+ "-" + id_number.substr(2, 2) + "-" + id_number.substr(4, 2);
     } else {
      date = '19' + year+ "-" + id_number.substr(2, 2) + "-" + id_number.substr(4, 2);
     }//end if
     displayResults[1] = options.displayDate[1] + date +"<br/>,";
    }//end if
   }//end if
   
   //display age
   if(options.displayAge[0] == true){ //start if statement
    if (id_number.length > 5){  //start if statement
     var year       = id_number.substr ( 0  , 2 );
     var nowYearNotCentury = currentTime.getFullYear() + '';
     nowYearNotCentury = nowYearNotCentury.substr(2,2);
     if (year <= nowYearNotCentury){
      year = '20' + year;
     } else {
      year = '19' + year;
     }//end if
     var birthDate = new Date(year);
     var age = currentTime.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();
     var m = currentTime.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth();
     if (m < 0 || (m === 0 && currentTime.getDate() < birthDate.getDate())) {
      age--;
     }
     displayResults[2] = options.displayAge[1]+ age +"<br/>,";
    }//end if
   }//end if
   
   //display gender
   if(options.displayGender[0] == true){ //start if statement
    if (id_number.length > 9){ //start if statement
     var MaleFemale = id_number.substr(6, 4);
     MaleFemale = (MaleFemale * 1) + 0;
     
     if ((MaleFemale >= 0) & (MaleFemale < 5000)){
      displayResults[3] = options.displayGender[2]+"<br/>,";
     }//end if
     
     if ((MaleFemale > 4999) & (MaleFemale < 10000)){
      displayResults[3] = options.displayGender[1]+"<br/>,";
     }//end if
    }//end if
   }//end if
   
   //display citizenship
   if(options.displayCitizenship[0] == true){ //start if statement
    if (id_number.length > 12){ //start if statement
     var citizen  = (id_number.substr ( 10 , 2 )*1);
     if ((citizen == 8) || (citizen == 9)){
      displayResults[4] = options.displayCitizenship[1]+"<br/>,";
     } 
     else if ((citizen == 18) || (citizen < 19)){
      displayResults[4] = options.displayCitizenship[2]+"<br/>,";
     }//end if
    }//end if
   }//end if
   
   //check validility of IDNO
   if(options.displayValid[0] == true){ //start if statement
    if (id_number.length == 13){ //start if statement
     var testResult = ValidateID(id_number);
     if (testResult[0] == 1){
      displayResults[0] = options.displayValid[1]+'<br/>,';
     } else {
      var errorMessage = '';
      for( count = 0 ; count < testResult[2].length ; count++ )
       errorMessage += testResult[2][count] + '';
      displayResults[0] = options.displayValid[2] + ": " + errorMessage +'<br/>,';
     }//end if
    }//end if
   }//end if
   
   //display function
   
   if(options.displayValid_id != "id_results"){
    element_type = $("#"+options.displayValid_id).get(0).tagName;
    displayResults[0] = displayResults[0].replace(/(<.*?>)/ig,"");
    displayResults[0] = displayResults[0].replace(/,/g , "");
    if(element_type == "DIV"){
     $("#"+options.displayValid_id).html(displayResults[0]);
    }else if(element_type == "INPUT"){
     $("#"+options.displayValid_id).val(displayResults[0]);
    }else if(element_type == "SELECT"){
     $("#"+options.displayValid_id).val(displayResults[0]);
    }else if(element_type == "SPAN"){
     $("#"+options.displayValid_id).text(displayResults[0]);
    }
   }else{
    if(displayResults[0] != " "){
     html = html+displayResults[0];
    }
   }
   if(options.displayDate_id != "id_results"){
    element_type = $("#"+options.displayDate_id).get(0).tagName;
    displayResults[1] = displayResults[1].replace(/(<.*?>)/ig,"");
    displayResults[1] = displayResults[1].replace(/,/g , "");
    if(element_type == "DIV"){
     $("#"+options.displayDate_id).html(displayResults[1]);
    }else if(element_type == "INPUT"){
     $("#"+options.displayDate_id).val(displayResults[1]);
    }else if(element_type == "SELECT"){
     $("#"+options.displayDate_id).val(displayResults[1]);
    }else if(element_type == "SPAN"){
     $("#"+options.displayDate_id).text(displayResults[1]);
    }
   }else{
    if(displayResults[1] != " "){
     html = html+displayResults[1];
    }
   }
   if(options.displayAge_id != "id_results"){
    element_type = $("#"+options.displayAge_id).get(0).tagName;
    displayResults[2] = displayResults[2].replace(/(<.*?>)/ig,"");
    displayResults[2] = displayResults[2].replace(/,/g , "");
    if(element_type == "DIV"){
     $("#"+options.displayAge_id).html(displayResults[2]);
    }else if(element_type == "INPUT"){
     $("#"+options.displayAge_id).val(displayResults[2]);
    }else if(element_type == "SELECT"){
     $("#"+options.displayAge_id).val(displayResults[2]);
    }else if(element_type == "SPAN"){
     $("#"+options.displayAge_id).text(displayResults[2]);
    }
   }else{
    if(displayResults[2] != " "){
     html = html+displayResults[2];
    }
   }
   if(options.displayGender_id != "id_results"){
    element_type = $("#"+options.displayGender_id).get(0).tagName;
    displayResults[3] = displayResults[3].replace(/(<.*?>)/ig,"");
    displayResults[3] = displayResults[3].replace(/,/g , "");
    if(element_type == "DIV"){
     $("#"+options.displayGender_id).html(displayResults[3]);
    }else if(element_type == "INPUT"){
     $("#"+options.displayGender_id).val(displayResults[3]);
    }else if(element_type == "SELECT"){
     $("#"+options.displayGender_id).val(displayResults[3]);
    }else if(element_type == "SPAN"){
     $("#"+options.displayGender_id).text(displayResults[3]);
    }
   }else{
    if(displayResults[3] != " "){
     html = html+displayResults[3];
    }
   }
   if(options.displayCitizenship_id != "id_results"){
    element_type = $("#"+options.displayCitizenship_id).get(0).tagName;
    displayResults[4] = displayResults[4].replace(/(<.*?>)/ig,"");
    displayResults[4] = displayResults[4].replace(/,/g , "");
    if(element_type == "DIV"){
     $("#"+options.displayCitizenship_id).html(displayResults[4]);
    }else if(element_type == "INPUT"){
     $("#"+options.displayCitizenship_id).val(displayResults[4]);
    }else if(element_type == "SELECT"){
     $("#"+options.displayCitizenship_id).val(displayResults[4]);
    }else if(element_type == "SPAN"){
     $("#"+options.displayCitizenship_id).text(displayResults[4]);
    }
   }else{
    if(displayResults[4] != " "){
     html = html+displayResults[4];
    }
   }
   
   if($("#id_results").length != 0){
    $('#id_results').html(html.replace(/,/g , ""));
   }else{
    html = html.replace(/(<.*?>)/ig,"");
    html = html.replace(/,/g , "\n");
    if (id_number.length == 13){
     alert(html);
    }
   }
   });//end of function  
   
   function ValidateID(id_number){
    var sectionTestsSuccessFull = 1;
    var MessageCodeArray   = [];
    var MessageDescriptionArray = [];
    var currentTime    = new Date();
    
    /* DO ID LENGTH TEST */
    if (id_number.length == 13){ 
     /* SPLIT ID INTO SECTIONS */
     var year       = id_number.substr ( 0  , 2 );
     var month      = id_number.substr ( 2  , 2 );
     var day        = id_number.substr ( 4  , 2 );
     var gender     = (id_number.substr ( 6  , 4 )*1);
     var citizen    = (id_number.substr ( 10 , 2 )*1);
     var check_sum  = (id_number.substr ( 12 , 1 )*1);
     
     /* DO YEAR TEST */
     var nowYearNotCentury = currentTime.getFullYear() + '';
     nowYearNotCentury = nowYearNotCentury.substr(2,2);
     if (year <= nowYearNotCentury){
      year = '20' + year;
     } else {
      year = '19' + year;
     }//end if
     if ((year > 1900) && (year < currentTime.getFullYear())){
      //correct
     } else {
      sectionTestsSuccessFull = 0;
      MessageCodeArray[MessageCodeArray.length] = 1;
      MessageDescriptionArray[MessageDescriptionArray.length] = 'Year is not valid, ';
     }//end if
     
     /* DO MONTH TEST */
     if ((month > 0) && (month < 13)){
      //correct
     } else {
      sectionTestsSuccessFull = 0;
      MessageCodeArray[MessageCodeArray.length] = 2;
      MessageDescriptionArray[MessageDescriptionArray.length] = 'Month is not valid, ';
     }//end if
     
     /* DO DAY TEST */
     if ((day > 0) && (day < 32)){
      //correct
     } else {
      sectionTestsSuccessFull = 0;
      MessageCodeArray[MessageCodeArray.length] = 3;
      MessageDescriptionArray[MessageDescriptionArray.length] = 'Day is not valid, ';
     }//end if
     
     /* DO DATE TEST */
     if ((month==4 || month==6 || month==9 || month==11) && day==31) {
      sectionTestsSuccessFull = 0;
      MessageCodeArray[MessageCodeArray.length] = 4;
      MessageDescriptionArray[MessageDescriptionArray.length] = 'Date not valid. This month does not have 31 days, ';
     }
     if (month == 2) { // check for february 29th
      var isleap = (year % 4 == 0 && (year % 100 != 0 || year % 400 == 0));
      if (day > 29 || (day==29 && !isleap)) {
       sectionTestsSuccessFull = 0;
       MessageCodeArray[MessageCodeArray.length] = 5;
       MessageDescriptionArray[MessageDescriptionArray.length] = 'Date not valid. February does not have ' + day + ' days for year ' + year +', ';
      }//end if
     }//end if
     
     /* DO GENDER TEST */
     if ((gender >= 0) && (gender < 10000)){
      //correct
     } else {
      sectionTestsSuccessFull = 0;
      MessageCodeArray[MessageCodeArray.length] = 6;
      MessageDescriptionArray[MessageDescriptionArray.length] = 'Gender is not valid, ';
     }//end if
     
     /* DO CITIZEN TEST */
     //08 or 09 SA citizen
     //18 or 19 Not SA citizen but with residence permit
     if ((citizen == 8) || (citizen == 9) || (citizen == 18) || (citizen == 19)){
      //correct
     } else {
      sectionTestsSuccessFull = 0;
      MessageCodeArray[MessageCodeArray.length] = 7;
      MessageDescriptionArray[MessageDescriptionArray.length] = 'Citizen value is not valid, ';
     }//end if
     
     /* GET CHECKSUM VALUE */
     var check_sum_odd         = 0;
     var check_sum_even        = 0;
     var check_sum_even_temp   = "";
     var check_sum_value       = 0;
     var count = 0;
     // Get ODD Value
     for( count = 0 ; count < 11 ; count += 2 ){
      check_sum_odd += (id_number.substr ( count , 1 )*1);
     }//end for
     // Get EVEN Value
     for( count = 0 ; count < 12 ; count += 2 ){
      check_sum_even_temp = check_sum_even_temp + (id_number.substr ( count+1 , 1 )) + '';
     }//end for
     check_sum_even_temp = check_sum_even_temp * 2;
     check_sum_even_temp = check_sum_even_temp + '';
     for( count = 0 ; count < check_sum_even_temp.length ; count++ ){
      check_sum_even += (check_sum_even_temp.substr( count , 1 ))*1;
     }//end for
     // GET Checksum Value
     check_sum_value = (check_sum_odd*1) + (check_sum_even*1);
     check_sum_value = check_sum_value + 'xxx';
     check_sum_value = ( 10 - (check_sum_value.substr( 1 , 1 )*1) );
     if(check_sum_value == 10)
      check_sum_value = 0;
     
     /* DO CHECKSUM TEST */
     if(check_sum_value == check_sum){
      //correct
     } else {
      sectionTestsSuccessFull = 0;
      MessageCodeArray[MessageCodeArray.length] = 8;
      MessageDescriptionArray[MessageDescriptionArray.length] = 'Checksum is not valid, ';
     }//end if
     
    } else {
     sectionTestsSuccessFull = 0;
     MessageCodeArray[MessageCodeArray.length] = 0;
     MessageDescriptionArray[MessageDescriptionArray.length] = 'IDNo is not the right length, ';
    }//end if
    
    var returnArray = [ sectionTestsSuccessFull, MessageCodeArray, MessageDescriptionArray];
    return returnArray;
   }//end function
 });

 };  
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.rsa_id_validator.js"></script>
<script>
$().ready(function() {
$('#idno').rsa_id_validator({
displayAge: [true,""],
displayDate_id: "date",
displayAge_id: "age",
displayGender_id: "gender",

});
});
</script>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<input type="text" name="idno" id="idno" size = "60" placeholder="Add the ID No of person here ie 5102185149089" />
<input type="text" name="date" id="date" placeholder="birthdate"/>
<input type="text" name="gender" id="gender" placeholder="gender">
<input type="text" name="age" id="age"  placeholder="Age">

</form>
</body>
</html>
```